# Cakephp 3 - how can I log all 404 errors in a separate file

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Bots or hackers bombard our site with requests to non-existant URLs like `/phpmyadmin/` etc, which renders my error-logs useless, because the errors I need to look at are so few and far in between. I don't want to skip logging them with the `skiplog` option, because I still might need to look at all those NotFoundException and MissingControllerExceptions at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure a new Log option in your app.php file:

```
'Log' => [
    '404' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Log\Engine\FileLog',
        'path' => LOGS,
        'file' => '404',
        'url' => env('LOG_ERROR_URL', null),
        'scopes' => ['404'],
    ],
    ...
```

Create a new File here: `src/Error/AppErrorHandler.php` with this content

```
namespace App\Error;

use Cake\Error\ErrorHandler;
use Cake\Log\Log;
use Exception;
class AppErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler
{
    /**
     * Handles exception logging
     *
     * @param \Exception $exception Exception instance.
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _logException(Exception $exception)
    {
        $notFoundExceptions = [
            'Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException',
            'Cake\Http\Exception\NotFoundException',
            'Cake\Http\Exception\UnauthorizedException',
        ];
        if (in_array(get_class($exception), $notFoundExceptions)) {
            return Log::error($this->_getMessage($exception), '404');
        } else {
            return parent::_logException();
        }
    }
}
```

Register this AppErrorHandler in the `bootstrap.php` file of your app. For me that meant replacing the registration of the default ErrorHandler `(new ErrorHandler(Configure::read('Error')))->register();` in line 109 like this:

```
(new \App\Error\AppErrorHandler(Configure::read('Error')))->register();
```